# How Do I connect two tables using the concept of foreign key and primary key?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and mysql stuff. I am working on reddit like webpage. So I made mysql tables they are as follows posts, comments etc. 
posts table columns are as follows-

- id
- title
- subreddit
- user
- timestamp
- url.

comments table columns are as follows

- id
- post
- timestamp
- user
- body.

So I want to connect the two like particular comment goes under a particular post. But user shouldn't care about that he just give the comments body and it automatically goes under a particular post with time of posting and name of user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id is the primary key of post table and FOREIGN KEY of comments table as post_id

the query should be like this

```
Select * from `post` inner join `comments` on `post`.`id` = `comments`.`post_id`
```